# Why is an SQL function taking so long when using variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have an SQL function and if I execute the function as per following code, it returns the result in 11 seconds.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyFunction('param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4', 'param5')
```

But if I execute the function as per following way, it return the result in 40 seconds.

```
DECLARE 
    @PARAM1 NVARCHAR(4), 
    @PARAM2 NVARCHAR(3), 
    @PARAM3 NVARCHAR(3), 
    @PARAM4 NVARCHAR(10), 
    @PARAM5 NVARCHAR(10)

SET @PARAM1 = 'param1'
SET @PARAM2 = 'param2'
SET @PARAM3 = 'param3'
SET @PARAM4 = 'param4'
SET @PARAM5 = 'param5'

SELECT * 
FROM MyFunction(@PARAM1, @PARAM2, @PARAM3, @PARAM4, @PARAM5)
```

Same parameter values and same result returned but why using variable is taking so long?

Comment: Its called [parameter sniffing](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/08/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and.html)

Comment: Recursion and there's more recursion to do? With no definition of the `FUNCTION` we can only really guess.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the function definition, as well as any relevant table and index definitions. Please also share a link to the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @DaleK it could just as easily be the result of dynamic slicing taking out entire portions of `case` expressions or whole joins, which can only be done with literals

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that either parameter sniffing or compiler shortcuts would apply to a user defined function.

However, for your example code, the parameters are different.  This code:

```
DECLARE 
    @PARAM1 NVARCHAR(4), 
    @PARAM2 NVARCHAR(3), 
    @PARAM3 NVARCHAR(3), 
    @PARAM4 NVARCHAR(10), 
    @PARAM5 NVARCHAR(10)

SET @PARAM1 = 'param1'
SET @PARAM2 = 'param2'
SET @PARAM3 = 'param3'
SET @PARAM4 = 'param4'
SET @PARAM5 = 'param5'
```

Is actually going to generate the values:

```
SET @PARAM1 = 'para'
SET @PARAM2 = 'par'
SET @PARAM3 = 'par'
SET @PARAM4 = 'param4'
SET @PARAM5 = 'param5'
```

because of the lengths of the parameter declarations.

If this is happening in your actual code, then the performance is different because the parameters are different.

Comment: Sorry for my code sample. It is parameter sniffing error.